# ffmpeg Unrecognized option 'vcodec libx264'

Tags: ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is trying to transcode webm files to mp4. It his the lambda using the following code to do the conversion:

```
const args = [
    "-i",
    inputFilename,
    "-vcodec libx264",
    "-r 30",
    "-y",
    mp4Filename,
];


try {
    const { error, output } = spawnSync(ffmpeg, args);
    console.log(`output: ${output}`);
    console.log(`error: ${error}`);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("ffmpeg failed...");
    console.log(error);
}
```

In my lambda, I'm seeing the following error:

```
output: ,,ffmpeg version 4.2.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Unrecognized option 'vcodec libx264'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

2021-09-08T15:19:46.644Z 9477062f-6afa-4a94-9900-6b28337d8c2a INFO output: ,,ffmpeg version 4.2.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6) configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg libavutil 56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100 libavcodec 58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100 libavformat 58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100 libavdevice 58. 8.100 / 58. 8.100 libavfilter 7. 57.100 / 7. 57.100 libswscale 5. 5.100 / 5. 5.100 libswresample 3. 5.100 / 3. 5.100 libpostproc 55. 5.100 / 55. 5.100 Unrecognized option 'vcodec libx264'. Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I'm using ffmpeg-4.2.2-amd64-static

Comment: `-vcodec` and `libx264` are two seperate arguments.

Comment: @tkausl oh. my. god. Thank you.